# Why do I have values ​outside the normalization range in my test set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, conv-neural-network, biological-neural-network

I got X_test values outside the range I specified in the normalization function, why I am getting those and how can I solve it? (This range [:,14:] in X_train and X_test where set because, in my dataset, the numerical values start in that column)

```
  from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
  scalar = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
  X_train[:,14:]=scalar.fit_transform(X_train[:,14:])
  X_test[:,14:]=scalar.transform(X_test[:,14:])
```

By plotting the X_train and X_test, we can appreciate that the values in X_train are within the range, while in the X_test there are some values outside that range.

This is X_train plot

[image]

This is X_test plot

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `fit` on the **training set**, as should be done.

This means that in the formula (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min), the **X_min and X_max** refer to the minimum and maximum values in your **training set** respectively, NOT the test set.

So if your **test set has values outside the minimum and maximum values** in your training set, those values in the test set will be mapped **outside** the `feature_range` that you provided, by simple arithmetic.

Shouldn't be anything to worry in your case, the test set scaled values are quite close to the `feature_range` you provided.

Just make sure the values in your test aren't on a scale totally different from those in your training set. You might consider removing the outliers in your test set to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You do everything right, and its the normal behavior.

Let's have a look at the offical [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) to give you an idea what is going on, the only difference is that we use the feature_range=(0, 1) instead of (-1,1).

```
data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]

>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()
>>> print(scaler.fit_transform(data))
[[0.   0.  ]
 [0.25 0.25]
 [0.5  0.5 ]
 [1.   1.  ]]
```

what happened here? The training data is transformed by:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

[where max and min in the feature range](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale)

So we getting in the range from 0 - 1

Now we are running it for the new test set, where we don't fit the scaler again, as you are doing also in your case:

```
>>> print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
[[1.5 0. ]]
```

So as you can see, the output is also outsite the range. That happens because for the first value the formula is:

```
X_std = (2 - -1) / (1 - -1) = 3/2
X_scaled = 3/2* (1+0) +0  = 1.5
```